# Table View Cell Does Not Reload When Scrolling

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a table view with prototype cells set up, when the view first loads the correct values for my label and slider are populated correctly for each cell. When i scroll down/up the the cells that go out of view on the screen do not seem to be reloading. They have a null value.

My data is source is an mutable array (localArray)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    LocalTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.labelOutlet.text = [[localArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] localChannel];
    cell.sliderOutlet.value = [[[localArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] localPercentage] intValue];

    return cell;
}
```

Logging

```
LOCAL CHANNEL: Webcast
LOCAL CHANNEL: The Stream
LOCAL CHANNEL: Email
LOCAL CHANNEL: Yammer
---Now scrolling
LOCAL CHANNEL: (null)
LOCAL CHANNEL: (null)
LOCAL CHANNEL: The Stream
```

Comment: Put a log statement in this method: `NSLog(@""LOCAL CHANNEL: %@", [[localArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] localChannel]);` and see what it outputs.

Comment: What debugging have you done? The question doesn't really contain enough information for anyone to help

Comment: Added logging to question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your code as provided below:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    LocalTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }

    cell.labelOutlet.text = [[localArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] localChannel];
    cell.sliderOutlet.value = [[[localArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] localPercentage] intValue];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Still not working. Could it be something to do with my custom cell?